# ndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, debugging, spyder, index-error

The programs runs the graph however it doesn't print the output results in the console for it detects an error found in line 103 which says "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices" How do I fix this?

This code performs the classification of heart disease by separating the predicted values in two sets, namely 0 for absence and 1 for presence where all the predicted values between 1 and 4 are replaced to 1 to check the model performance

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pylab as pl
from itertools import cycle
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.svm import SVC 

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Loading and pruning the data
dataset = genfromtxt('cleveland_data.csv',dtype = float, delimiter=',')
#print dataset
X = dataset[:,0:12] #Feature Set
y = dataset[:,13]   #Label Set

#Replacing 1-4 by 1 label
for index, item in enumerate(y):
    if not (item == 0.0):
        y[index] = 1
print(y)
target_names = ['0', '1']

#Method to plot the graph for reduced Dimesions
def plot_2D(data, target, target_names):
     colors = cycle('rgbcmykw')
     target_ids = range(len(target_names))
     plt.figure()
     for i, c, label in zip(target_ids, colors, target_names):
         plt.scatter(data[target == i, 0], data[target == i, 1],
                    c=c, label=label)
     plt.legend()
     plt.savefig('Problem 2 Graph')

# Classifying the data using a Linear SVM and predicting the probability of disease belonging to a particular class
modelSVM = LinearSVC(C=0.001)
pca = PCA(n_components=5, whiten=True).fit(X)
X_new = pca.transform(X)

# calling plot_2D
plot_2D(X_new, y, target_names)


#Applying cross validation on the training and test set for validating our Linear SVM Model
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X_new, y, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8, random_state=0)
modelSVM = modelSVM.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Linear SVC values with split")
print(modelSVM.score(X_test, y_test))

modelSVMRaw = LinearSVC(C=0.001)
modelSVMRaw = modelSVMRaw.fit(X_new, y)
cnt = 0
for i in modelSVMRaw.predict(X_new):
    if i == y[i]:
       cnt = cnt+1
print("Linear SVC score without split")
print(int(cnt)//303)

#Applying the Principal Component Analysis on the data features
modelSVM2 = SVC(C=0.001,kernel='rbf')

#Applying cross validation on the training and test set for validating our Linear SVM Model
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = cross_validation.train_test_split(X_new, y, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8, random_state=0)
modelSVM2 = modelSVM2.fit(X_train1, y_train1)
print("RBF score with split")
print(modelSVM2.score(X_test1, y_test1))

modelSVM2Raw = SVC(C=0.001,kernel='rbf')
modelSVM2Raw = modelSVM2Raw.fit(X_new, y)
cnt1 = 0
for i in modelSVM2Raw.predict(X_new):
        if i == y[i]:
           cnt1 = cnt1+1
print("RBF score without split")
print(float(cnt1)//303)

#Using Stratified K Fold
skf = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=5)
for train_index, test_index in skf:
   # print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train3, X_test3 = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train3, y_test3 = y[train_index], y[test_index]
modelSVM3 = SVC(C=0.001,kernel='rbf')
modelSVM3 = modelSVM3.fit(X_train3, y_train3)
print("Stratified K fold score")
print(modelSVM3.score(X_test3, y_test3))

modelSVM3Raw = SVC(C=0.001,kernel='rbf')
modelSVM3Raw = modelSVM3Raw.fit(X_new, y)
cnt2 = 0
for i in modelSVM3Raw.predict(X_new):
        if i == y[i]:
           cnt2 = cnt2+1
print("On PCA valued X_new")
print(float(cnt2)//303)

        #Text interpretation
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 1.5))
t = fig.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Problem 1 \nTesting Linear SVC values using Split \n0.5491803278688525 \nTesting with RBF using split \n0.4918032786885246 \nTesting using stratified with K folds \n0.5423728813559322',
ha='center', va='center', size=15)
text.set_path_effects([path_effects.path_2d()])
plt.show()
```

The program only runs the graph but doesn't show its results. I expect the console to print the results/interpretation of the SVM models and their values.

Comment: what is line 103? there are no line numbers.  check to see if whatever being returned is a tuple.  I have had that when a tuple is returned and I passed the tuple on to another function when I should have passed an element of the tuple to it

Comment: for i in modelSVM2Raw.predict(X_new):
        if i == y[i]:
           cnt1 = cnt1+1

Comment: for idx, i in enumerate(modelSVM2Raw.predict(X_new)):
        if i == y[idx]:    … I thing you are trying to slice y with an object and not something like an integer, assuming 'y' contains the same type of objects that your model is creating.  Enumerate removes the issues associated with … for i in range(len(something)):